# Images in list do not float correctly

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists

I'm trying to make a list of images, 2 per row.

The uneven rows (1, 3, 5, etc.) should have a small image first, and a wide one second. The even rows (2, 4, 6, 8, etc.) should have the wide image first and the smaller one second.

I'm now at row 3, and I cannot get the small image to the left for whatever reason. As you can see in the image below it floats to the right.

My code is very basic, and Dreamweaver displays it correctly in its Split function.

HTML:

```
<div id="portfolio-screen"></a>
    <ul>
            <li><img src="images/portfolio-jaar1.png" width="228"/></li>
            <li><img src="images/portfolio-pr1_2.png" width="500"/></li>
            <li><img src="images/portfolio-pr1_4.png" width="500"/></li>
            <li><img src="images/portfolio-pvs1.png" width="228"/></li>     
            <li><img src="images/portfolio-jaar2.png" width="228"/></li>
            <li><img src="images/portfolio-pr2_2.png" width="500"/></li>
    </ul>                   
</div>
```

CSS

```
#portfolio-screen       {margin-top: 8px; width: 768px; height: 602px; background-color:#37322d; overflow: auto;}
#portfolio-screen li    {margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 8px; float: left;}
```

For some reason it is not allowed to post images, so I have supplied a link to one: http://oi51.tinypic.com/b63vkk.jpg

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a broken `</a>` in there.

Secondly, make sure your unorder list has **Margin and padding of 0**

Lastly, mess with JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/NT4DS/10/

*Instead of floats try inline-block*

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this - the CSS height for the images could be removed for your size needs.

HTML

```
<div id="portfolio-screen">
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="images/portfolio-jaar1.png" class="imgSmall" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/portfolio-pr1_2.png" class="imgLarge" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/portfolio-pr1_4.png" class="imgLarge" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/portfolio-pvs1.png" class="imgSmall" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/portfolio-jaar2.png" class="imgSmall" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/portfolio-pr2_2.png" class="imgLarge" />
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
 height:20px;
}
.imgSmall {
 width:228px;
}
.imgLarge {
 width: 500px;
}
#portfolio-screen {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 768px;
 height: 602px;
 background-color:#37322d;
}
#portfolio-screen ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 15px;
 width: 768px;
}
#portfolio-screen li {
 margin-top: 8px;
 margin-left: 8px;
 display: inline-block;
}
#portfolio-screen li:nth-child(odd) {
 margin:0;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5qREV/

Comment: Ok, it turns out that I can keep whatever code I had and simply add the line "img {height:144px;}"

and it works. funny, guess there were some issues with the resizing (my images are bigger than the size they appear in on the webpage)

Comment: Please, do not use the `width` attribute, this is best for CSS, and add the `alt` for W3C validation. It's just good practice.